# utf-8 unicode in html and utf-8_general_ci in mysql

Tags: unicode

I have Mysql database with collation utf-8 general_ci

in HTML text is shown as `????????`

P.S

I am using

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
```

and this

```
<meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
```

In Mysql Database text is shown as needed but in HTML shown as `????????`
P.S It's georgian unicode

Comment: Don’t use MySQL’s `utf8` – [use `utf8mb4` instead](http://mths.be/utf8mb4).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use "set_charset" function after connecting to Mysql  database.